# Admob banner ad and scrollView inside constraint layout

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I have faced a problem with xml layout file, when trying to add admob banner and scrollView inside constraint layout the banner appears above scroll view please check the image bellow

this is the code I used In xml layout file for main3activity but it didn't work

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.macbookpro.Main3Activity">


    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollview1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"


            >


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
                android:text="@string/title1"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/soutitle3"
                android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/soutext3" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/soutitle4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:text="@string/soutitle4"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/soutitle4"
                android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/soutext4" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/soutitle5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:text="@string/soutitle5"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/soutitle5"
                android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/soutext5" />



        </RelativeLayout>


    </ScrollView>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-apppub3940256099942544/6300978111"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I think its against google's policies to put banner above text, so any suggestions ?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps ConstrainLayout is not the best tool, I think you should use a [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) and use layaout_above like this:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_above="@+id/scrollview1"
    ... />
```

Comment: I added RelativeLayout but the layout below didn't work so I tried android:layout_above="@+id/adView" and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding android:layout_above="@+id/adView" to scrollView